# If I separate the form and input components from the web component, submitHandler does not run

Tags: javascript, html, components, web-component

I am currently trying to implement a form submission event using a web component.

The public input component has been created, and I am trying to create a separate form component and insert the input component into this form.

However, if I insert it using a slot, the form submission function itself does not run at all.

However, if I directly enter the input and button properties in the form's template, the submission function works normally.

What's the problem?? I would like to know the solution.

### - BasicComponent.js

```js
class BasicComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(template) {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    const temp = document.createElement("template");
    temp.innerHTML = template;
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(temp.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  addEventListenerToElement(selector, event, handler) {
    const element = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector);
    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener(event, handler.bind(this));
    }
  }

  dispatchCustomEvent(
    eventName,
    detail,
    options = { bubbles: true, composed: true }
  ) {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent(eventName, {
        detail,
        bubbles: options.bubbles,
        composed: options.composed,
      })
    );
  }
}

export default BasicComponent;
```

### - FormComponent.js

```js
import BasicComponent from "../basic/BasicComponent.js";
import { template } from "./template.js";

class FormComponent extends BasicComponent {
  constructor() {
    super(template);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.addEventListenerToElement("form", "submit", this.submitFormHandler);
  }

  submitFormHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit");
  }
}

customElements.define("form-component", FormComponent);
```

### - FormComponent Template (not working)

```js
export const template = `<form><slot name="input-slot"></slot><slot name="button-slot"></slot></form>`;
```

### - html (not working)

```html
    <form-component>
        <my-input-component
          type="text"
          placeholder="placeholder"
          slot="input-slot
        ></my-input-component>

        <button slot="button-slot" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form-component>
```

### - When input and buttons are directly inserted into the template (is working)

```js
export const template = `<form><input type="text"/><button type="submit">submit</button></form>`;
```

### - html (is working)

```html
    <form-component>
    </form-component>
```

### - InputComponent.js

```js
import { template } from "./template.js";
import BasicComponent from "../basic/BasicComponent.js";

class MyInputComponent extends BasicComponent {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["type", "placeholder", "slot"];
  }

  constructor() {
    super(template);
    this.inputElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    this.addEventListenerToElement("input", "input", this.handleInput);
  }

  handleInput(e) {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;

    console.log(inputValue);
    this.dispatchCustomEvent("inputChanged", { value: inputValue });
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === "type") {
      this.inputElement.type = newValue;
    } else if (name === "placeholder") {
      this.inputElement.placeholder = newValue;
    } else if (name === "slot") {
      this.inputElement.slot = newValue;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define("my-input-component", MyInputComponent);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.